# How to approximate bid and ask volume?

Tags: equities, technical-analysis, volume

https://www.tradingtechnologies.com/xtrader-help/x-study/technical-indicator-definitions/volume-delta-vol/

Bid and ask volume is defined as the volume traded at bid or ask prices.

Given only OHLCV data, how to approximate the bid and ask volume?

Comment: From OHLCV data, I do not think that you can. I imagine the Trading Technolgies software you mention monitors the bid, the ask and the individual trades continuously as they happen and keeps the running sum of the volume that occurred at the bid and at the ask.

Answer (score 1):

The bigger issue is the validation of the method.

It is technically possible to model such things, I am providing an example that is used as a teaching tool for modeling three-sided coins (landing on the edge is included).  https://artowen.su.domains/courses/306a-1011/threesidedcoin_amstat.pdf

However, you have to build a functional form yourself.  Even if you did that, you have to find a way to validate the model.

Can it be done, yes it can be.  Validating that it is a good idea or that it works, that is a different question.

**EDIT**

As far as I have been able to determine, nobody has done that in the literature; or, if a paper exists, then the search terms obscure it.  As I said, you will have to build the functional form yourself and test it.

If you can explain to yourself how the volume data would impact the price data, then you can test a form.

Comment: But this answer doesn't seem to provide any value to my question. A more useful answer would be something like (if you knew somebody had done anything that you suggested) any works on how to approximate the bid/ask volume using OHLCV data.

Comment: I will edit it, but as far as I know, nobody has ever done anything like that in the literature.